# Dynamic number of columns for words with different length

Tags: html, css, html-lists, dynamic-columns

So I tried to create an ul with multiple li-entries.
These word entries in the li are supposed to be displayed in columns, however I wanted these columns to be dynamic,
meaning that longer words create fewer columns and that shorter words create more columns.
The page is supposed to be displayed in DINA4 format.
I already attempted to use Flexbox & Grid, however that only works when I define a fixed amount of columns, thus not having it be dynamic.

If possible I would like to avoid using javaScript as the page should be made up of CS and HTML alone.
[Short words with more columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFqqB.png)
[Longs words with fewer columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3Oz2.png)

With grid auto-fill I get this results:
[Result with long words](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jwut9.png)

My code:

```
  ul.words-o {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  gap: 0 20px;
}
```

Comment: do you have any code to share to show what you have done and what goes wrong ? grid and auto-fill should do .https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/ -/-  https://gridbyexample.com/examples/example37/

Comment: I've tried it with auto-fit 
`ul.words-o {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  gap: 0 20px;
}`
But I get with auto-fill the same result

Comment: 200px is quiet a lot for a single word.

Comment: 200px is not enough for some of the words, so they overlap
i have uploaded a picture of the result in my post
and I have forgotten to say, that the result has to be on DINA4 format

Comment: oh yes , forgot about his behavior, you might need javascript to update that minmax value , here is an idea https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/YzXoQyO to adapt to the grid template

Comment: this doesnt work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use javascript to update the minmax value via a custom CSS var(--);

```js
var bigW = "0";
// go through all children and keep the widest value
for (let e of document.querySelectorAll("ol > li")) {
  elW = e.offsetWidth;
  if (elW < 5) {} else if (elW > bigW) {
    bigW = elW
  }
// upddate the CSS var()
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--min-content", bigW + 1 + "px");
  // delay time to display as a grid untill every children's width have been tested
  setTimeout(document.querySelector("ol#ol-grid").classList.add("grid"), 10);// if your computer is slow, increase it a bit , if your eye notices it, its too long
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.grid {
  display: grid;
}
ol {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(
    auto-fit,
    minmax(var(--min-content,200px), max-content)
  );
  gap: 20px;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid;
}
```

```html
<ol id="ol-grid">  
  <li>lkgdsflkdgsh</li>
  <li>klfqh</li>
  <li>Lorem</li>
  <li> ipsum</li>
  <li> dolor</li>
  <li> sit</li>
  <li> amet</li>
  <li>consectetuer</li>
  <li> adipiscing</li>
  <li> elit.</li>
   <li>Aliquam</li>
  <li> tincidunt</li>
  <li> mauris</li>
  <li> eu</li>
  <li> risus.</li>
   <li>VestibulumVestibulum</li>
  <li> auctor</li>
  <li> dapibus</li>
  <li> neque</li>
</ol>
```

[codepen to play with](https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/bGpmVob)

---

Also,
You might use `column-count` and javascript to reassign a value to `column-count` `onload` and  `onresize`

example

```js
function checkGridWidth() {
  let colCount = 12; // set col numbers to start with
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--colCount', colCount); // reset while on resize needs it
  let list = document.querySelector("#ol-grid");
  let vw = list.parentNode.offsetWidth;
  let myW = list.offsetWidth;
  if (myW > vw) {
    let dif = myW - vw;
    let colW = (myW / colCount);
    let newColCount = vw / colW;
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--colCount', Math.floor(newColCount - 1));
  }
}
window.onresize = checkGridWidth;
window.onload = checkGridWidth;
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div {
  margin: 3cm;
}

@media print {
  div>h1 {
    display: none;
  }
}

ol {
  padding: 5px;
  column-gap: 5px;
  column-fill: balance;
  column-count: var(--colCount, 12);
  min-width: max-content;
  /* you need it so it can overflow its parent, js will use this width value*/
  margin: auto;
  border: solid;
  /*see me*/
}

li {
  display: block;
  border: solid;
  /*see me*/
}

li:not(:last-of-type) {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1> Redraw the right amount of column than can fit in here if too wide</h1>
  <ol id="ol-grid">
    <li>lkgdsflkdgsh</li>
    <li>klfqh</li>
    <li>Lorem</li>
    <li> ipsum</li>
    <li> dolor</li>
    <li> sit</li>
    <li> amet</li>
    <li>consectetuer</li>
    <li> adipiscing</li>
    <li> elit.</li>
    <li>Aliquam</li>
    <li> tincidunt</li>
    <li> mauris</li>
    <li> eu</li>
    <li> risus.</li>
    <li>VestibulumVestibulum</li>
    <li> auctor</li>
    <li> dapibus</li>
    <li> neque</li>
    <li>lkgdsflkdgsh</li>
    <li>klfqh</li>
    <li>Lorem</li>
    <li> ipsum</li>
    <li> dolor</li>
    <li> sit</li>
    <li> amet</li>
    <li>consectetuer</li>
    <li> adipiscing</li>
    <li> elit.</li>
    <li>Aliquam</li>
    <li> tincidunt</li>
    <li> mauris</li>
    <li> eu</li>
    <li> risus.</li>
    <li>VestibulumVestibulum</li>
    <li> auctor</li>
    <li> dapibus</li>
    <li> neque</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

[codepen to play with](https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/dyMgOrz)

Comment: The second code you've posted yesterday has done what i wanted. Thank you :) This one doesn't do the thing that i want

Comment: I meant this one: https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/bGpmVob

Comment: @MintyFresh :) okay, i added it to the answer , so it makes sens to you and can be usefull to someone else.